# Is it legal in Egypt to sell BTC, and is that available there?

Tags: legal, money-transfer, business, usa

My friend from USA is trying to send money to me but he can't do that through Moneygram or WU. 
So he asked if it's possible to send the money through Bitcoin.

So, I'm not sure if it's going to work out.

Answer (score 1):

According to https://legal-or-not.com/bitcoin/egypt-bitcoin-status/, Bitcoin is legal in Egypt. On the wiki for list of countries on stances on bitcoin, Egypt is not listed.

In 2016, an Egyptian dentist was arrested for trading bitcoins for USD. Note, he was **not** trading bitcoins but rather exchanging them for USD. He was arrested for scamming, money laundering, and as I said above, exchanging through foreign currencies.

Thus, because there is very little information about the Egyptian's government on bitcoin, be careful, but it should be ok. Hopefully my answer helps you out.